# What optimization technique does ghci use to speed up recursive map?

Tags: haskell, optimization, expression

Say I have the following function:

```
minc = map (+1)
natural = 1:minc natural
```

It seems like it unfolds like this:

```
1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc...
1:2:minc(minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc...
1:2:minc(2:minc(2:minc(2:minc(2:minc(2:minc(2:minc(2:minc(2:minc(minc...
1:2:3:minc(3:minc(3:minc(3:minc(3:minc(3:minc(3:minc(3:minc(minc(minc...
...
```

Although it's lazily evaluated, to build each new number `n` in the list is has to unfold an expression `n` times which gives us `O(N^2)` complexity. But by the execution time I can see that the real complexity is still linear!

Which optimization does Haskell use in this case and how does it unfold this expression?

Comment: I compiled and timed: got 1s for 10000000 and 12.94s for 100000000. Looks pretty linear. How did you get your result?

Comment: Never mind, what I said is totally bogus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of naturals is being shared between each recursive step. The graph is evaluated like this.

```
1:map (+1) _
 ^         |
 `---------'

1: (2 : map (+1) _)
      ^          |
      `----------'

1: (2 : (3 : map (+1) _)
           ^          |
           `----------'
```

This sharing means that the code uses O(n) time rather than the expected O(N^2).

Comment: Indeed, having linear complexity in my example means there is some kind of list sharing going on. But how does GHC know specifically when and how to optimize? Does it specifically look for such cases? GHC doesn't even normally do common subexpression elimination, so I am surprised some kind of memoization is done here.

Comment: @egdmitry It isn't really optimization, it is just laziness (which includes not evaluating an expression *more* than once) and thunks referring circularly to themselves because they're defined that way. Basically it's what every Haskell compiler is expected to do even if it's *not* being particularly clever.

Comment: There is no "optimization" at play here, the only reason the evaluation is shared is because there is only one `natural`, only one place in memory where this list exists. At first it is only a thunk `1:minc natural` but when you evaluate the second element, it becomes a list of 1 cons `map (+1) (1: ref to tail of natural)` then 1 cons 2 cons `map (+1) (2: ref to tail of tail of natural)`, as you see the next step will be O(1), and so on.

Comment: Interestingly, `test x = x : map (+1) (test x)` is O(N^2). So once there is an argument GHC doesn't see that this is the same thunk?

Comment: That is correct. GHC will generally only share thunks if they directly refer to the same thing. Your test will gain the sharing if we write `test x = let test' = x : map (+1)  test' in x`. In this case we can see test' can be shared. This transformation is call the static argument transformation and there has been talk about enabaling it in GHC [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9374)

Answer (score 2):

> to build each new number `n` in the list is has to unfold an expression `n` times which gives us *O*(*N*<sup>2</sup>) complexity.

Not quite. The complexity of unfolding the first *N* numbers this way is indeed *O*(*N*<sup>2</sup>)<sup>**Apparently I'm wrong here**[1]</sup>. But if you request *only* the *N*-th number, then it actually evaluates like this:

```
(!!n) $ 1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc...
(!!n-1) $ minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc...
(!!n-1) $ (1+1):minc(minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc...
            -- note that `(1+1)` isn't actually calculated!
(!!n-2) $ minc(minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc...
(!!n-2) $ ((1+1)+1):minc(minc(minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc...
            -- again, neither of the additions is actually calculated.
(!!n-3) $ minc(minc(minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc...
(!!n-3) $ ((...)+1):minc(minc(minc(minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc(1:minc...
...
(!!n-n) $ ((...+1)+1) : minc(minc(...minc(minc(1:minc(...
           ╰─ n ─╯
(!!0) $ (n+1) : _
n+1
```

Which takes only a fixed number of two steps per increase in *N*, plus *N* additions once it's reached the index – that's still *O*(*N*) all in all.

The crucial thing here is that basically, `map` is only applied once to the entire list. It's completely lazy, i.e. to yield a `_:_` thunk it only needs to know that the list has at least *length* 1, but the actual elements don't matter at all.

This way, what we've written as `minc(minc(...(minc(1 : ...` is replaced by `(... + 1) : minc(...` in only one step.

---

<sup>[1]</sup><sub>Turns out that even if we *sum* the first *N* numbers, it's done in *O*(*N*). I don't know how.</sub>

Comment: Hmm, I can see how it can calculate an element in the list by index in N steps, but how does it calculate all elements when `take` is called? It seems that in the thunks expression the part that is a calculation for `N+1` is not shared with the one for `N`. What would be the proper way to test that it really is O(N^2) when taking first N number? I was doing `(sum . take 100000000) natural`.

Comment: Hm, it looks indeed like summing the first _N_ elements can _still_ be done in _O_ (_N_). That's remarkable! Can't say right now how this works...

Comment: All those computations are _shared_, there is only one `minc` list, and there's no need to recompute its content at several points.